# Why did I lose rep from this reversal?

Tags: support, serial-voting

today I saw that I had 180 points taken from me. I see that one user who I had answered a question to had up voted many of my posts, so I guess that is fair for some to be taken. BUT, I had answered other questions and spent time and got real accepted answers and up votes and still lost that rep! that doesn't seem fair! why does this happen, and what can be done?

Comment: The reversal occurred at 3am SE time; that is, the automatic script detected an odd voting pattern from one user to your account. The script is then designed to remove the votes. This script is not all bad. If someone would have downvoted you, you would have received the points back.

Comment: I see, thanks. But will I have lost rep from other users or just that one?

Comment: And I am curious about the down vote? I was under the impression this was the right place to ask these type of questions , no?

Comment: If it was one user, only votes by that user would have been targeted. If it was two users, then those two. I don't know how many users it was so I can't say.

Comment: Didn't downvote but this question has definitely been asked before.

Comment: Yea I know, I looked at the others but I wasn't exactly sure about the process and such. anyways, thanks

Answer (score 4):

> why does this happen,

This is explained on the [Help Center page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) which  is linked from the entry of your reputation history showing the reversal.

> and what can be done?

Nothing.